# How can I change the filled color of stacked area plot in DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, area, stacked

I want to change the filled color in the stacked area plots drawn with Pandas.Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
ax = df.plot.area(linewidth=0);
```

[The area plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzy.png)

Now I guess that the instance return by the plot function offers the access to modifying the attributes like colors.

But the axes classes are too complicated to learn fast. And I failed to find similar questions in the Stack Overflow.

So can any master do me a favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API of matplotlib is really complex, but here [artist Module](https://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist) gives a very plain illustration. For the bar/barh plots, the attributes can be visited and modified by *.patches*, but for the area plot they need to be with *.collections*.

To achieve the specific modification, use codes like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
ax = df.plot.area(linewidth=0);

for collection in ax.collections:
    collection.set_facecolor('#888888')

highlight = 0
ax.collections[highlight].set_facecolor('#aa3333')
```

Other methods of the collections can be found by run

```
dir(ax.collections[highlight])
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is using the 'color' parameter:

**Soln 1: dict**
Simply pass a dict of {column name: color}

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], )

ax = df.plot.area(color={'b':'0', 'c':'#17A589', 'a':'#9C640C', 'd':'#ECF0F1'})
```

**Soln 2: sequence**
Simply pass a sequence of color codes (it will match the order of your columns).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], )

ax = df.plot.area(color=('0', '#17A589', '#9C640C', '#ECF0F1'))
```

No need to set linewidth (it will automatically adjust colors). Also, this wouldn't mess with the legend.

Answer (score 3):

Use 'colormap' (See the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) for more details):

```
ax = df.plot.area(linewidth=0, colormap="Pastel1")
```

[image]